# Eclipse: Exported library fail to instantiate oracle driver ojdbc.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jar

I have a library that contains functionality to connect to on oracle database. When I export this library (as a JAR) and use it in the main project, it gives an exception when loading the driver with class.forname. It obviously cannot find the ojdbc driver. I included this driver in the build path and as exported library.

I tested and used the driver directly from the main project, and it work, it connects to oracle db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your driver is a jar file, and when you export the app as a jar file, that driver will be a jar file in a jar file. For that scenario you either need a special classloader or put the driver jar file in the classpath of your main program.

Comment: also be aware of the licensing issue. You are not allowed to package oracle's driver into your jar file if you want to release your project publicly.

Comment: Actually, for the time being, i don’t' have the sources of the main project, only the sources of the library. I have checked the classpath system environment variable. I have also put the jodbc.jar in the same library as the main project (which is an executable jar) but still it does not work. Normally when executing a Jar, the Java VM should look for classes in the classpath and it should work, right ?

Comment: you could try to run your main project like this: `java -cp path-to/ojdbc14.jar:path-to/your-jar projects.main.Clazz` (in the directory where the projects compiled .class files are), then it will be on the classpath.

Comment: also -> of course it does not work when you put ojdbc.jar in the same jar as the main project. My answer states, that you cannot simply put a jar under/in a jar!

Comment: Thanks, it worked running with the command line as you mentioned above, but with ";" instead of ":"

Answer (score 0):

Explore your exportedjar by using WinRar and check if it contains a jar under jar.

Comment: I opened it and it does not contain a jar under jar.

Comment: Simple, one package dbconnexion with one class DBAcessor. In the exported jar, there is no ojdbc.jar, but in the .classpath there is an entry for the library : classpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="ojdbc14(oracle).jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>

Comment: Try to create a jar from command prompt which should have ojdbc.jar and give it a try. Seems like dbconnexion  or DBAcessor is trying to create a connection, but jar is not in theie scope. Exported jar should have ojdbc14.jar (Whichever version you are using). Create a jar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html    If you want to use eclipse then copy the ojdbc.jar in your project. when you select the export-> select the resources to export-> In right hand side you will see .classpath and. project, ojdbc.jar should also be there and it should be checked.

Comment: In Eclipse, ojdbc.jar does not appear on the resources list (in the dame list as .classpath and. project) in the explort dialog, although ojdbc.jar is referenced as a library in the project. What do you mean by copying the ojdbc.jar in my project ?

Comment: once again: you cannot put a jar in a jar and expect it to work! especially if the outer jar is a library, that you want to use in some other project. it might work if the jar is meant to run as a program (because eclipse then supplies a special class loader with the jar)